# MySQL selectively pull distinct rows from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Table A has ID and Name fields and the following data
1 Joe 
2 John 
2 John 
2 John 
4 George 
4 George 
4 George

Table B has ID and a different field
1 ABC
1 XYZ
3 ABC
4 ABC
4 GHI
4 XYZ

I would like to have a query that would return only one record from Table A, if there, but will have multiple rows if Table B contains multiples. 
I would also like to have an indicator that there was no joining record (Null)
Desired results:
1 Joe ABC
1 Joe XYX
2 John Null
3 Null ABC
4 George ABC
4 George GHI
4 George XYZ

Characteristics:
Brings back Joe from Table A twice because there are 2 rows in Table B with same ID
Brings back John from Table A once even though there are no rows in Table B to indicate the same
Brings back ID 3 from Table B once even though there are no rows in Table A to indicate the same
Brings back George from Table A three times because there are 3 rows in Table B with same ID

Thank you

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Join by ID and apply DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, A.name, B.diff
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B  USING(ID);
```

Consider also

```
SELECT ID, A.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(B.diff) AS 'other stuff'
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B  USING(ID);
```